# Json Recursive function to filter and return object in exact form as request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, mapping

Please i need help i want to loop through this data and get only specific data from
the children objects then return it back in the same nested format as the parent.

```
const req = {
    "document": {
        "id": "0:0",
        "name": "Document",
        "type": "DOCUMENT",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "0:1",
                "name": "Page 1",
                "type": "CANVAS",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "1:3",
                        "name": "Rectangle 1",
                        "type": "RECTANGLE",
                        "blendMode": "PASS_THROUGH",
                        "absoluteBoundingBox": {
                            "x": -183,
                            "y": -257,
                            "width": 414,
                            "height": 349
                        },
                        "constraints": {
                            "vertical": "TOP",
                            "horizontal": "LEFT"
                        },
                        "fills": [
                            {
                                "blendMode": "NORMAL",
                                "type": "SOLID",
                                "color": {
                                    "r": 0.13307291269302368,
                                    "g": 0.41923439502716064,
                                    "b": 0.4375,
                                    "a": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "strokes": [],
                        "strokeWeight": 1,
                        "strokeAlign": "INSIDE",
                        "effects": [],
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "1:3",
                                "name": "Rectangle 1",
                                "type": "RECTANGLE",
                                "blendMode": "PASS_THROUGH",
                                "absoluteBoundingBox": {
                                    "x": -183,
                                    "y": -257,
                                    "width": 414,
                                    "height": 349
                                },
                                "constraints": {
                                    "vertical": "TOP",
                                    "horizontal": "LEFT"
                                },
                                "fills": [
                                    {
                                        "blendMode": "NORMAL",
                                        "type": "SOLID",
                                        "color": {
                                            "r": 0.13307291269302368,
                                            "g": 0.41923439502716064,
                                            "b": 0.4375,
                                            "a": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "strokes": [],
                                "strokeWeight": 1,
                                "strokeAlign": "INSIDE",
                                "effects": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "1:4",
                                "name": "TEST",
                                "type": "TEXT",
                                "blendMode": "PASS_THROUGH",
                                "absoluteBoundingBox": {
                                    "x": -39,
                                    "y": -155,
                                    "width": 105,
                                    "height": 72
                                },
                                "constraints": {
                                    "vertical": "TOP",
                                    "horizontal": "LEFT"
                                },
                                "fills": [
                                    {
                                        "blendMode": "NORMAL",
                                        "type": "SOLID",
                                        "color": {
                                            "r": 1,
                                            "g": 1,
                                            "b": 1,
                                            "a": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "strokes": [],
                                "strokeWeight": 1,
                                "strokeAlign": "OUTSIDE",
                                "effects": [],
                                "characters": "TEST",
                                "style": {
                                    "fontFamily": "Poppins",
                                    "fontPostScriptName": "Poppins-Regular",
                                    "fontWeight": 400,
                                    "fontSize": 48,
                                    "textAlignHorizontal": "CENTER",
                                    "textAlignVertical": "TOP",
                                    "letterSpacing": 0,
                                    "lineHeightPx": 56.25,
                                    "lineHeightPercent": 100,
                                    "lineHeightUnit": "INTRINSIC_%"
                                },
                                "characterStyleOverrides": [],
                                "styleOverrideTable": {}
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "2:0",
                                "name": "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.",
                                "type": "TEXT",
                                "blendMode": "PASS_THROUGH",
                                "absoluteBoundingBox": {
                                    "x": -161,
                                    "y": -83,
                                    "width": 384,
                                    "height": 126
                                },
                                "constraints": {
                                    "vertical": "TOP",
                                    "horizontal": "LEFT"
                                },
                                "fills": [
                                    {
                                        "blendMode": "NORMAL",
                                        "type": "SOLID",
                                        "color": {
                                            "r": 1,
                                            "g": 1,
                                            "b": 1,
                                            "a": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "strokes": [],
                                "strokeWeight": 1,
                                "strokeAlign": "OUTSIDE",
                                "effects": [],
                                "characters": "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,\nis dummy  text used in laying out print, graphic or\nweb designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown \ntypesetter in  the 15th century who is thought to have\nscrambled parts of  Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et \nMalorum for use in a type specimen book.",
                                "style": {
                                    "fontFamily": "Poppins",
                                    "fontPostScriptName": "Poppins-Regular",
                                    "fontWeight": 400,
                                    "fontSize": 14,
                                    "textAlignHorizontal": "LEFT",
                                    "textAlignVertical": "TOP",
                                    "letterSpacing": 0,
                                    "lineHeightPx": 16.40625,
                                    "lineHeightPercent": 100,
                                    "lineHeightUnit": "INTRINSIC_%"
                                },
                                "characterStyleOverrides": [],
                                "styleOverrideTable": {}
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1:4",
                        "name": "TEST",
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "blendMode": "PASS_THROUGH",
                        "absoluteBoundingBox": {
                            "x": -39,
                            "y": -155,
                            "width": 105,
                            "height": 72
                        },
                        "constraints": {
                            "vertical": "TOP",
                            "horizontal": "LEFT"
                        },
                        "fills": [
                            {
                                "blendMode": "NORMAL",
                                "type": "SOLID",
                                "color": {
                                    "r": 1,
                                    "g": 1,
                                    "b": 1,
                                    "a": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "strokes": [],
                        "strokeWeight": 1,
                        "strokeAlign": "OUTSIDE",
                        "effects": [],
                        "characters": "TEST",
                        "style": {
                            "fontFamily": "Poppins",
                            "fontPostScriptName": "Poppins-Regular",
                            "fontWeight": 400,
                            "fontSize": 48,
                            "textAlignHorizontal": "CENTER",
                            "textAlignVertical": "TOP",
                            "letterSpacing": 0,
                            "lineHeightPx": 56.25,
                            "lineHeightPercent": 100,
                            "lineHeightUnit": "INTRINSIC_%"
                        },
                        "characterStyleOverrides": [],
                        "styleOverrideTable": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2:0",
                        "name": "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.",
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "blendMode": "PASS_THROUGH",
                        "absoluteBoundingBox": {
                            "x": -161,
                            "y": -83,
                            "width": 384,
                            "height": 126
                        },
                        "constraints": {
                            "vertical": "TOP",
                            "horizontal": "LEFT"
                        },
                        "fills": [
                            {
                                "blendMode": "NORMAL",
                                "type": "SOLID",
                                "color": {
                                    "r": 1,
                                    "g": 1,
                                    "b": 1,
                                    "a": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "strokes": [],
                        "strokeWeight": 1,
                        "strokeAlign": "OUTSIDE",
                        "effects": [],
                        "characters": "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,\nis dummy  text used in laying out print, graphic or\nweb designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown \ntypesetter in  the 15th century who is thought to have\nscrambled parts of  Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et \nMalorum for use in a type specimen book.",
                        "style": {
                            "fontFamily": "Poppins",
                            "fontPostScriptName": "Poppins-Regular",
                            "fontWeight": 400,
                            "fontSize": 14,
                            "textAlignHorizontal": "LEFT",
                            "textAlignVertical": "TOP",
                            "letterSpacing": 0,
                            "lineHeightPx": 16.40625,
                            "lineHeightPercent": 100,
                            "lineHeightUnit": "INTRINSIC_%"
                        },
                        "characterStyleOverrides": [],
                        "styleOverrideTable": {}
                    }
                ],
                "backgroundColor": {
                    "r": 0.8980392217636108,
                    "g": 0.8980392217636108,
                    "b": 0.8980392217636108,
                    "a": 1
                },
                "prototypeStartNodeID": null,
                "prototypeDevice": {
                    "type": "NONE",
                    "rotation": "NONE"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "components": {},
    "schemaVersion": 0,

}

// this is the object i want to loop through to get all the children in same nested format as it is
```

```js
//here is my function for looping 

 getValuesByKey(object, key) {
    var values = [];

    function r(obj) {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
          obj[k].forEach(r);
          return;
        }
        if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
          r(obj[k]);
          return;
        }

        k === key &&
          !~values.push({
            // belongsTO: obj.id + "_" + obj.characters,
            type: obj.characters,
            content: obj.characters ? obj.characters : "",
            style: obj.style ,
          });
      });
    }

    r(object);
    return values;
  }




console.log(getValuesByKey(req, "name"));
// but it doesn't give me back the array in same nested format as the parent
```

Please i need help i want to loop through this data and get only specific data from
the children objects then return it back in the same nested format as the parent.

```
// expected output should be 
// basically outing out the data and given it back in the same nested way it was initially

[
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "TEXT",
            "content": "this is a text",
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Poppins",
                "fontPostScriptName": "Poppins-Regular",
                "fontWeight": 400,
                "fontSize": 48,
                "textAlignHorizontal": "CENTER",
                "textAlignVertical": "TOP",
                "letterSpacing": 0,
                "lineHeightPx": 56.25,
                "lineHeightPercent": 100,
                "lineHeightUnit": "INTRINSIC_%"
            },
            "children": [
                "type": "TEXT",
                "content": "this is a text",
                "style": {
                    "fontFamily": "Poppins",
                    "fontPostScriptName": "Poppins-Regular",
                    "fontWeight": 400,
                    "fontSize": 48,
                    "textAlignHorizontal": "CENTER",
                    "textAlignVertical": "TOP",
                    "letterSpacing": 0,
                    "lineHeightPx": 56.25,
                    "lineHeightPercent": 100,
                    "lineHeightUnit": "INTRINSIC_%"
                },
                "type": "TEXT",
                "content": "this is a text",
                "style": {
                    "fontFamily": "Poppins",
                    "fontPostScriptName": "Poppins-Regular",
                    "fontWeight": 400,
                    "fontSize": 48,
                    "textAlignHorizontal": "CENTER",
                    "textAlignVertical": "TOP",
                    "letterSpacing": 0,
                    "lineHeightPx": 56.25,
                    "lineHeightPercent": 100,
                    "lineHeightUnit": "INTRINSIC_%"
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "type": "TEXT",
            "content": "this is a text",
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Poppins",
                "fontPostScriptName": "Poppins-Regular",
                "fontWeight": 400,
                "fontSize": 48,
                "textAlignHorizontal": "CENTER",
                "textAlignVertical": "TOP",
                "letterSpacing": 0,
                "lineHeightPx": 56.25,
                "lineHeightPercent": 100,
                "lineHeightUnit": "INTRINSIC_%"
            }
        }

    ]

]
```

Comment: can you add your expected output how do you want

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: Where does the `content` data in the output come from (such as "this is a text")?  I don't see it in the input.

Comment: Ah, missed that, and thanks, @Scott

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether your sample output is supposed to actually match your sample input.  If so, I don't understand it, I guess.  But if they are only somewhat related samples, then something like this might do:

```js
const extract = ({type, characters, style, children}) => ({
  ... (type ? {type} : {}),
  ... (characters ? {content: characters} : {}),
  ... (style ? {style} : {}),
  ... (children ? {children: children .map (extract )} : {})
})

const req = {document: {id: "0: 0", name: "Document", type: "DOCUMENT", children: [{id: "0: 1", name: "Page 1", type: "CANVAS", children: [{id: "1: 3", name: "Rectangle 1", type: "RECTANGLE", blendMode: "PASS_THROUGH", absoluteBoundingBox: {x: -183,  y: -257, width: 414, height: 349}, constraints: {vertical: "TOP", horizontal: "LEFT"}, fills: [{blendMode: "NORMAL", type: "SOLID", color: {r: .13307291269302368, g: .41923439502716064, b: .4375, a: 1}}],strokes: [],strokeWeight: 1, strokeAlign: "INSIDE", effects: [],children: [{id: "1: 3", name: "Rectangle 1", type: "RECTANGLE", blendMode: "PASS_THROUGH", absoluteBoundingBox: {x: -183, y: -257, width: 414, height: 349}, constraints: {vertical: "TOP", horizontal: "LEFT"}, fills: [{blendMode: "NORMAL", type: "SOLID", color: {r: .13307291269302368, g: .41923439502716064, b: .4375, a: 1}}],strokes: [],strokeWeight: 1, strokeAlign: "INSIDE", effects: []}, {id: "1: 4", name: "TEST", type: "TEXT", blendMode: "PASS_THROUGH", absoluteBoundingBox: {x: -39, y: -155, width: 105, height: 72}, constraints: {vertical: "TOP", horizontal: "LEFT"}, fills: [{blendMode: "NORMAL", type: "SOLID", color: {r: 1, g: 1, b: 1, a: 1}}],strokes: [],strokeWeight: 1, strokeAlign: "OUTSIDE", effects: [],characters: "TEST", style: {fontFamily: "Poppins", fontPostScriptName: "Poppins-Regular", fontWeight: 400, fontSize: 48, textAlignHorizontal: "CENTER", textAlignVertical: "TOP", letterSpacing: 0, lineHeightPx: 56.25, lineHeightPercent: 100, lineHeightUnit: "INTRINSIC_%"}, characterStyleOverrides: [],styleOverrideTable: {}}, {id: "2: 0", name: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.", type: "TEXT", blendMode: "PASS_THROUGH", absoluteBoundingBox: {x: -161, y: -83, width: 384, height: 126}, constraints: {vertical: "TOP", horizontal: "LEFT"}, fills: [{blendMode: "NORMAL", type: "SOLID", color: {r: 1, g: 1, b: 1, a: 1}}],strokes: [],strokeWeight: 1, strokeAlign: "OUTSIDE", effects: [],characters: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,\nis dummy  text used in laying out print, graphic or\nweb designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown \ntypesetter in  the 15th century who is thought to have\nscrambled parts of  Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et \nMalorum for use in a type specimen book.", style: {fontFamily: "Poppins", fontPostScriptName: "Poppins-Regular", fontWeight: 400, fontSize: 14, textAlignHorizontal: "LEFT", textAlignVertical: "TOP", letterSpacing: 0, lineHeightPx: 16.40625, lineHeightPercent: 100, lineHeightUnit: "INTRINSIC_%"}, characterStyleOverrides: [],styleOverrideTable: {}}]}, {id: "1: 4", name: "TEST", type: "TEXT", blendMode: "PASS_THROUGH", absoluteBoundingBox: {x: -39, y: -155, width: 105, height: 72}, constraints: {vertical: "TOP", horizontal: "LEFT"}, fills: [{blendMode: "NORMAL", type: "SOLID", color: {r: 1, g: 1, b: 1, a: 1}}],strokes: [],strokeWeight: 1, strokeAlign: "OUTSIDE", effects: [],characters: "TEST", style: {fontFamily: "Poppins", fontPostScriptName: "Poppins-Regular", fontWeight: 400, fontSize: 48, textAlignHorizontal: "CENTER", textAlignVertical: "TOP", letterSpacing: 0, lineHeightPx: 56.25, lineHeightPercent: 100, lineHeightUnit: "INTRINSIC_%"}, characterStyleOverrides: [],styleOverrideTable: {}}, {id: "2: 0", name: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.", type: "TEXT", blendMode: "PASS_THROUGH", absoluteBoundingBox: {x: -161, y: -83, width: 384, height: 126}, constraints: {vertical: "TOP", horizontal: "LEFT"}, fills: [{blendMode: "NORMAL", type: "SOLID", color: {r: 1, g: 1, b: 1, a: 1}}],strokes: [],strokeWeight: 1, strokeAlign: "OUTSIDE", effects: [],characters: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,\nis dummy  text used in laying out print, graphic or\nweb designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown \ntypesetter in  the 15th century who is thought to have\nscrambled parts of  Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et \nMalorum for use in a type specimen book.", style: {fontFamily: "Poppins", fontPostScriptName: "Poppins-Regular", fontWeight: 400, fontSize: 14, textAlignHorizontal: "LEFT", textAlignVertical: "TOP", letterSpacing: 0, lineHeightPx: 16.40625, lineHeightPercent: 100, lineHeightUnit: "INTRINSIC_%"}, characterStyleOverrides: [],styleOverrideTable: {}}],backgroundColor: {r: .8980392217636108, g: .8980392217636108, b: .8980392217636108, a: 1}, prototypeStartNodeID: null, prototypeDevice: {type: "NONE", rotation: "NONE"}}]}, components: {}, schemaVersion: 0};

console .log(
  extract (req.document) 
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

For each node we test, we extract the `type`, `characters`, `style`, and `children` nodes that it has, allowing for the case that they don't exist.

Then the `type` and `style` nodes are added directly to the output, the `characters` node is renamed `content`, and we recursively map over the `children` node with our function.  For each property, we only include it in the output if the input had a value.  But if you wanted to change that behavior, it's simple enough.  For instance, it looks as though you want to default `content` to the empty string.  You could simply update that relevant line, replacing

```js
  ... (characters ? {content: characters} : {}),
```

with

```js
  content: characters || '',
```

Note that we keep the nesting of the entire document node passed to us.  So unlike your sample output, we end up with a structure like this:

```
DOCUMENT
    CANVAS
        RECTANGLE
            RECTANGLE
            TEXT
            TEXT
        TEXT
        TEXT
```

But your sample output seemed only to care about those `TEXT` nodes.  It's not clear to me how you would want to proceed from there, because you can't easily eliminate the non-text nodes.  (All of them are in DOCUMENT > CANVAS, but that also includes a RECTANGLE node that has another RECTANGLE node and two TEXT nodes for children.  It's hard to see how to consolidate anything.  But that may or may not be important.  This might get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @scott helps alot